# Snowflake query_history gets reset after warehouse suspension

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the following query to retrieve query history from my Snowflake database.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table(MY_DATABASE.information_schema.query_history(
  end_time_range_start => dateadd(HOUR, -4, current_timestamp()),
  current_timestamp()
));
```

Oddly, if the warehouse (size: XS) I am using gets suspended after a period of inactivity, the next time I attempt to retrieve query history- the history that was there prior to the warehouse's suspension is gone.

I could not find anything documented to explain this.

Anyone run into this issue or related documentation that could explain this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I can't explain exactly the limitations of that information schema query you are running (some of them only return like 10,000 rows or like you said, once the warehouse turns off), but it's a limited view into the actual query history. You can use the `snowflake` database for all query history.

It's a massive table so make sure you put filters on it. Here's an example query to access it:

```
USE DATABASE snowflake;
USE SCHEMA account_usage;

SELECT *
FROM query_history
WHERE start_time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00' AND '2020-01-03 00:00'
  AND DATABASE_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME'
  AND USER_NAME = 'USERNAME'
ORDER BY START_TIME DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! This workaround does work, however I am at a loss as to why the information_schema.query_history (which is more efficient to query) does not seem to store the last 7 days of queries as indicated by the docs.

Comment: it's probably part of the caching that the warehouses do behind the scenes. for example, if you keep the warehouse on all the time queries will be able to access cached queries but if it terminates and turns back on, you lose all the cached results. this must be similar, but I couldn't 100% accurately respond to that.

Comment: Hi Itay, this behaviour doesn't sound quite right...it's not a caching thing related to the virtual warehouses - in fact the results should be available for this database using different virtual warehouses altogether to access them. If you do use another WH to run the query do the results appear? Some things I would check: a) make sure that the database in question hasn't been recreated in the interim b) make sure you are using correct role to run the query c) check that the 7 days worth of retention for this query hasn't expired between runs

Comment: Thanks Mike - I tried all of these things, the queries should definitely be returned from the query_history, they are only a few minutes old, and they appear in the results until the warehouse is suspended then resumed again.

Comment: This saved me when I accidentally deleted a worksheet and needed to recover the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1: Your question states that after a period of inactivity, does not specify what is the period of inactivity.

"after a period of inactivity, the next time I attempt to retrieve query history- the history that was there prior to the warehouse's suspension is gone."

If its beyond 7 days then the data can be found from account_usage table. Below is the link of difference between INFORMATION_SCHEMA and ACCOUNT_USAGE.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema

2: Your query does not specify USER_NAME or WAHREHOUSE_NAME in your query so it could be that before the output of your queries before suspension of warehouse may have moved beyond 4 hours period as in your predicate. If you can increase the time period and check if behaviour still exists.

3: In general its not advisable to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get query history unless your application requires data without any latency. If possible use ACCOUNT_USAGE table to get query history information.

Here is what I did.

1: Created an XS warehouse

2: Set auto_suspend to 5 minutes

3: Ran few queries

4: Ran your query (which does not specify user_name or warehouse_name) meaning you are searching for history from all users.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table(MY_DATABASE.information_schema.query_history(
  end_time_range_start => dateadd(HOUR, -4, current_timestamp()),
  current_timestamp()
));
```

5: Returned output of few 100 records.

6: Used additional where clause to check for data of my user which ran few queries before auto_suspend of Warehouse and it returned few records.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table(MY_DATABASE.information_schema.query_history(
  end_time_range_start => dateadd(HOUR, -4, current_timestamp()),
  current_timestamp()
))
WHERE USER_NAME = 'ADITYA';
```

7: Waited for 10 minutes so that my warehouse is auto_suspended.

8: Repeat point 5 and point 6 and again it returned records as expected.

Comment: Tip: Consider using three backticks (```) on both ends of your SQL queries to treat them as a contiguous code block. (It might also be easier to read these if they were formatted, though I acknowledge that the OP also didn't apply any such formatting.)

Comment: I suspended the warehouse after 1 minute and looked for queries that happened less than 10 mins before... so this is definitely not an issue with the queries expiring after 4 hours (I also ran this with no such filter) or 7 days.